# Java: Using printf() to BOTH left justify and right justify on SAME line

Tags: java, printf

In Java, how could I use printf() to **both** left justify and right justify output on the **same** line consistently?
This is the code for *everything* left justified:

```
System.out.println("   ********************L********R");
String[] array = {"apple", "pie", "cheese"};
double[] array2 = {0.003, 1245, 19.979};
double[] array3 = {0.2, 1, 9};
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
{
    System.out.printf("   %-10s%-10.2f%.2f%n", array[index], array2[index], array3[index]);
}
```

This is the output that *everything* is left justified:

```
   ********************L********R
   apple     0.00      0.20
   pie       1245.00   1.00
   cheese    19.98     9.00
```

What I want instead if that for the third elements (0.20, 1.00, 9.00) to be **right** justified. I indicated in the output above that "L" is left justified, but I want the variables to be right justified where the "R" is. How can I right justify the output on the right (0.20, 1.00, 9.00), while also keeping the output on the left (apple, pie, cheese) left justified?

Comment: Oh, I realized my mistake. I thought that putting %10.2f on the last column would start counting spaces from (0.00, 1245.00, 12.98) and since they were all of different lengths, I thought the third column would be off by one, two, three. I see now, that the -10.2f on the second column alligned evenly 10 spaces, so the third column would start after those 10 spaces. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Try `System.out.format("   %-10s%-10.2f%10.2f%n")`

Comment: Try "   %-10s%-10.2f%10.2f%n"

Answer (score 1):

Your last parameter, `%.2f`, isn't specifying a number of characters to right justify.  Assuming you want it to be 10 characters, like the other parameters, you'd probably want `%10.2f`.